# An error occured when executing the cache:clear --no-warmup” while installing fosuserbundle

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I am installing fosuserbundle using composer but I am getting error while installing it.

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]

Warning: constant(): Couldn't find constant Monolog\Logger::DEBUG in /home/trainee/web/projects/Symfony-demo/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/MonologBundle/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php line 110                                           

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]                                                         
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

I am using this command

```
php composer.phar require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle --prefer-dist
Please provide a version constraint for the friendsofsymfony/user-bundle requirement: dev-master
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of my problem. For that, first I need to install composer using

```
php composer.phar install
```

then I need to install fosuserbundle using

```
php composer.phar require fosuserbundle/user-bundle --prefre-dist
```

so it will be installed